# append to multi-dimensional subdocument

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

I want to add a new filed like "email" for each sub document in groups

```
{ "_id" : 10, 
  "groups" : [ 
        { 

                "members" : ["Mark"], 
                "name" : "My Friends" 
        },
        { 

                "name" : "Colleagues" 
        }, 
        { 

                "name" : "Buddies" 
        },..... 
],.. }
```

Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

I am trying tis but its not working 
db.users.update({},{$push: {"groups.$.email": 'abc'} }, true, true);

Comment: The question needs more information like what values would you set for each sub document's `email` field?

Comment: db.users.update({},{$push: {"groups.$.email": 'abc'} }, false, true);

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you need to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator.  Specifically, you want:

```
db.users.update({_id:10,groups:{$elemMatch:{name:"My Friends"}}},{$push: {"groups.$.email":"abc"}},false,true);
```

The important part is that the $elemMatch will set the array pointer to the exact element that matched, so you can push at that point.